# 3 dynamic checkboxes divs communicating

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I am trying to create 3 divs with checkboxes inside that communicate. 
Following this example https://jsfiddle.net/o04bfazk/ I would like to be able for exampele to 1]when I check the '1' (which has class A0) to check automatically all checkboxes in the second and third div that also have that same A0 class. Then I'd like to be able to do the same with the third div independently.

```
<script>
    function myFunction(ele){

        var cing = ele.className;
        //alert(cing);
        $('input.'+cing).click(function(){
            //alert('2');
            $('input.'+cing).prop('checked',this.checked)
        });
    }
</script>

<script>
    function myFunctionin(elle){
        var cinci = elle.className.split(' ')[1];
        alert(cinci);
        //var cincirr = elle.className.split(' ')[0];
        $('input.'+cinci).click(function(){
            $('input.'+cinci).prop('checked',this.checked)
        });

    }
</script>
```

I created the following 2 functions, the first one works correctly, but when I add the third div and the second function I get classes conflicts and I don't know how to do.

Comment: Should the binding be one-way or two-way? I.e. if you deselect a checkbox with the class of A0 in div 3 should that also deselect it in div 1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. Use `$.each()` to access all the relevant checkboxes.

```js
function myFunction(elle) {
  var cinci = $(elle).attr("class");
  $('input.' + cinci).each(function() {
    $('input.' + cinci).prop('checked', this.checked)
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="content">
  <div class="main-content">
    <form method="post" action="">
      <div class="col-xs-3">
        <div class="pic-container">
          <div class="checkbox">
            <label><span><input type="checkbox" name="" id="" onclick="myFunction(this)" class="A0" value="A0">1</span>
              <br>
            </label>
            <label><span><input type="checkbox" name="" id="" onclick="myFunction(this)" class="C" value="C">2</span>
              <br>
            </label>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <div class="col-xs-3">
        <div class="pic-container">
          <div class="checkbox">
            <label><span><input type="checkbox" name="" id="" onclick="myFunctionin(this)" class="A0 A00" value="A00">11</span>
              <br>
            </label>
            <label><span><input type="checkbox" name="" id="" onclick="myFunctionin(this)" class="A0 A01" value="A01">12</span>
              <br>
            </label>
            <label><span><input type="checkbox" name="" id="" onclick="myFunctionin(this)" class="A0 A02" value="A02">13</span>
              <br>
            </label>
            <label><span><input type="checkbox" name="" id="" onclick="myFunctionin(this)" class="A0 A03" value="A03">14</span>
              <br>
            </label>
            <label><span><input type="checkbox" name="" id="" onclick="myFunctionin(this)" class="A0 A06" value="A06">15</span>
              <br>
            </label>
            <label><span><input type="checkbox" name="" id="" onclick="myFunctionin(this)" class="A0 A07" value="A07">16</span>
              <br>
            </label>
            <label><span><input type="checkbox" name="" id="" onclick="myFunctionin(this)" class="A0 A08" value="A08">17</span>
              <br>
            </label>
            <label><span><input type="checkbox" name="" id="" onclick="myFunctionin(this)" class="C C00" value="C00">18</span>
              <br>
            </label>
            <label><span><input type="checkbox" name="" id="" onclick="myFunctionin(this)" class="C C01" value="C01">19</span>
              <br>
            </label>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <div class="col-xs-3">
        <div class="pic-container">
          <div class="checkbox">
            <label><span><input type="checkbox" name="" id="" class="A0 A00" value="A00AA">21</span>
              <br>
            </label>
            <label><span><input type="checkbox" name="" id="" class="A0 A00" value="A00AB">22</span>
              <br>
            </label>
            <label><span><input type="checkbox" name="" id="" class="A0 A00" value="A00AC">23</span>
              <br>
            </label>
            <label><span><input type="checkbox" name="" id="" class="A0 A00" value="A00AD">24</span>
              <br>
            </label>
            <label><span><input type="checkbox" name="" id="" class="C C00" value="C00AC">25</span>
              <br>
            </label>
            <label><span><input type="checkbox" name="" id="" class="C C00" value="C00AD">26</span>
              <br>
            </label>
            <label><span><input type="checkbox" name="" id="" class="C C00" value="C00AE">27</span>
              <br>
            </label>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
  </div>
</section>
```

Is this you are expecting?

Comment: exactly! working perfectly by changing it on both functions! Could you tell me why I should have used each and not click?

Comment: your requirement is to check the relevant check boxes while clicking the `A0` (1)  or `C` (2) right?

Comment: Then you don't need to apply click event for those elements. By using `$.each()` you can access those check boxes and do necessary actions .

Comment: Please mark it as answer, if this answer helped you.
To mark it as an answer hover the cursor near the down arrow of my answer. there you will find an tick mark, check that one.